# delete whitespace from the end of string in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

please I want to know how to delete whitespaces from the end of string in dart .
ex :

```
String name ="(  Sana .  Harun  )";
```

when I use this code

```
print(sana.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"),""));
```

it just delete from the beggining and not from the end , and print Like this :**(Sana.Harun )** .. there is a space between Harun and ) .
I want to delete the space between **Harun** and **)**

Can any one help me , please ?

Comment: Try adding a `+` after the `\b\s` in the RegExp. As written, it only removes *one* space, not all the spaces after a word break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this function/method !

```
String getWithoutSpaces(String s){
      String tmp = s.substring(1,s.length-1);
      while(tmp.startsWith(' ')){
       tmp = tmp.substring(1);
      }
      while(tmp.endsWith(' ')){
       tmp = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length-1);
      }

  return '('+tmp+')';
}
```

[image: pic]

Comment: I used this method @Naveen Avidi .. and it works with me  ...  Thank you for your help  .....  String validate_Strings(String name , String last) 
{ String n =name.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"),""); String f= n.replaceAll(" ", ""); String c= last.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"),""); String l = c.replaceAll(" ", ""); String u = '('+f+'.'+l+')'; print(u); return u; }

Comment: If it's useful and helped you ! Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution , is to use this code

```
print(sana.replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

so the space between **Harun** and **)** disappear

Comment: Maybe you should look at stopping the spaces getting there in the first place. I am presuming they are there as a result of user input?

Comment: Yes , that's because the user input ,so ?i want when user enter something , the code delete every space between the letters , but I solved the problem now .. with this code  ..     String validate_Strings(String name , String last)
  {
   String n =name.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"),"");
   String f= n.replaceAll(" ", "");

   String c=  last.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"),"");
   String l = c.replaceAll(" ", "");

   String u = '('+f+'.'+l+')';
   print(u);
   return u;
  }   @GrahamD